# Прозрачность спрайта в юнити

Tags: unity3d

Как программно поменять прозрачность спрайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SpriteRenderer sr;
Color color=sr.color;
color.a=0.5f;
sr.color=color;
```